# How to check admin login in the app using parse? [iOS]

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Who has understood how to check at the entrance to the user application administrator rights? [**iOS**]
In the parse documentation is mentioned only how to create PFRole:

```
PFRole *role = [PFRole roleWithName:@"Administrator" acl:roleACL];
[role saveInBackground];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query for the roles that particular user has been assigned for. You can do this way.

```
PFQuery query = [PFRole query];
[query whereKey:@"users" equalTo:user]; 
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

// get list of roles the user has been assigned for and check if that user has been assigned administrator
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you really checked the Parse iOS documentation, your answer is already given there:-

https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#roles/iOS

**Still for clarification:**

*You have to use **PFRole**  which  is a subclass of PFObject, and has all of the same features PFObject except  some additions of specific to management of roles.*

**Here is the code to find all users roles specified for single Parse DB.**

```
PFQuery query = [PFRole query]; 
[query whereKey:@"users" equalTo:user]; 
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:(NSArrayobjects, NSError *error) {

// objects are the roles the user is assigned to

}];
```